# Orchard multi tenant with multiple hostnames

Tags: orchardcms, multi-tenant

Is it possible to have multiple hostnames pointing to the same tenant. E.g. I want my-website.nl and mywebsite.nl pointing to the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be bad for SEO. You should pick one and have the others permanently redirect to it.

UPDATE: to redirect, you can use IIS url rewrite by editing the web.config, or you can use the Rewrite module for Orchard: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.RewriteRules

Although I don't recommend it, you can also specify a comma-separated list of host names in tenant configuration and get the result you wanted initially (I should have remembered that as I wrote that code).

Comment: OK, didnt know that. Is that permanent redirect something I can achieve with Orchard, or do use my hosting provider for this.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. It helped. I will mark the post as answered, but I do think the answer should be: no its not possible, use permanent redirect instead. By the way, wouldn't it be a nice feature to have the possibility to add multiple hosts to one tenant or domain and have Orchard detect it and apply rewriting for us, instead of me editing the web.config? Just asking:)